# Missing BPM information

Tags: itunes, windows

I have hundreds of songs that are missing BPM information in ITunes.  How do I force ITunes to update the BPM?

Please note that deleting and re-adding songs back is not a very good option for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that iTunes will update BPM information from the file.

- Create a playlist in iTunes of a few songs that do not have BPM Information
- Use any software that evaluates BPM information and writes it to the song file (I used Virtual DJ).
- In iTunes go to your playlist, click to select the first song, and simply press and hold the DOWN arrow.

Answer (score 0):

iTunes won’t do this itself, but I found this tool very helpful http://www.beatunes.com/itunes-automatic-bpm-detection.html

Comment: Alternatively, if you're on OS X, try [BeatGauge](http://www.tagtraum.com/beatgauge.html) by the same company (that I happen to work for).

Answer (score 0):

I can't find a way for iTunes to do it, but i have had success with [BPMer](http://www.wildbits.com/bpmer/)